# how to know on which window drive(C,D,E), my ubuntu is installed

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, windows

My ubuntu is installed on /dev/sda11 partition , but how to know on which window drive(C,D,E) , ubuntu is installed

Comment: This is both EOL (13.04) and OT (Windows' problem), Windows do not see other partitions than their FAT and NTFS's, unless you install the drivers.

Comment: Windows can not see your Ubuntu files. It is not on any of this drives. Open diskmgmt.msc program to see the partitions in windows.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I'm sorry but you asking a question about an Ubuntu distribution which has reached already its end of lifetime. You might want to consider upgrading. I'm voting to close the question therefore as off-topic because its about an EOL release of Ubuntu.

Comment: IMHO This isn't *specific* to release, but OT because it's Windows' problem, so flag as not Ubuntu not EOL

Comment: As @NonStandardModel said, Windows is not able to read or even detect the `ext4` (or similar) file systems that Linux uses. To Windows, your Ubuntu partitions look like unformatted, empty partitions. If you want to share a partition between Windows and Ubuntu, you must make an additional partition and format it as FAT or NTFS. Ubuntu on the other hand can of course access all of your Windows partitions.

Comment: There are also free drivers for Windows to see ext partitions, for example `ext2fat`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's none of them. Windows can not read the filesystem on your Ubuntu partitions and doesn't mount them.

If you look at whatever the windows partitioning tool is, you will see your Ubuntu partition as a partition of an unknown type.

Comment: The Ubuntu partitions won't show as "Unallocated space", they will show as a partition of an unknown type, at least in the standard diskmgmt.msc.